# Can 2 user accounts write to the same SQL Server database but not overwrite existing data?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a SQL Server 2008 R2 and TIBCO application is writing data into this. Now, the application is going thru an upgrade. The existing service account (say sa1) is writing data to the db. We have created a new service account (say sa2) for testing the upgrade. if we point sa2 to write to the production environment before go-live, the existing data (created by sa1) shall be overwritten. In that case, how to test the upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

In order to test the upgrade, you could create a test database from your production database e.g. backup the production database then restore it on SQL Server with a new name such as Test_DB and run a trial upgrade pointing your TIBCO application to this Test_DB.